# ESP32 kernel panic at random (network_event)

Tags: ethernet, esp32

I'm working with an ESP at the moment and I have written alot of code that works on it's own, but once merged, it doesn't.

My code boots, but then I get the following;

```
09:00:18.780 -> Device is now in pay-mode
09:00:18.780 -> ETH Started
09:00:22.779 -> ETH Connected
09:00:22.812 -> ETH MAC: 3C:61:05:30:A9:7F, IPv4: 192.168.207.102, FULL_DUPLEX, 100Mbps
09:00:22.812 -> Registering Device
09:00:22.812 -> Just the main loop
09:00:23.798 -> Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Unhandled debug exception)
09:00:23.798 -> Debug exception reason: Stack canary watchpoint triggered (network_event) 
09:00:23.832 -> Core 1 register dump:
09:00:23.832 -> PC      : 0x4011ee2b  PS      : 0x00060e36  A0      : 0x801120df  A1      : 0x3ffb8630  
09:00:23.832 -> A2      : 0x3ffb8ca4  A3      : 0x3ffb8ca4  A4      : 0x3ffbc668  A5      : 0x3ffbc65c  
09:00:23.832 -> A6      : 0x3ffbc6bc  A7      : 0x00000000  A8      : 0xb9e3b68c  A9      : 0x00000040  
09:00:23.832 -> A10     : 0x7b8a813d  A11     : 0x3ffbd650  A12     : 0x3ffb8ca4  A13     : 0x3ffd8ca4  
09:00:23.866 -> A14     : 0x5d484383  A15     : 0x37ac32fc  SAR     : 0x00000010  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000001  
09:00:23.866 -> EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x4000c349  LEND    : 0x4000c36b  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  
09:00:23.866 -> 
09:00:23.866 -> ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000
09:00:23.866 -> 
09:00:23.866 -> Backtrace: 0x4011ee2b:0x3ffb8630 0x401120dc:0x3ffb8ca0 0x40113175:0x3ffb8cd0 0x4011321b:0x3ffb8d00 0x40121b15:0x3ffb8d30 0x401115ff:0x3ffb8d70 0x401278e8:0x3ffb8d90 0x4012803b:0x3ffb8e20 0x401145f5:0x3ffb8e40 0x40114635:0x3ffb8e60 0x400d4871:0x3ffb8e80 0x400d426b:0x3ffb9100 0x400d4371:0x3ffb9130 0x400d2745:0x3ffb9150 0x400d2ad3:0x3ffb9400 0x400d396a:0x3ffb9470 0x400d3a74:0x3ffb9560 0x40089996:0x3ffb9590
09:00:23.899 -> 
09:00:23.899 -> Rebooting...
```

I have no idea what is going on here, or why I'm getting this error. after a couple of minutes, the main loop just runs (so I get the whole time "Just the main loop" in my console.

I'm using an ETH module and I do some API calls. Can this be that the ESP looses power or doesn't get enough power or so? I'm kinda at a loss why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Decode the backtrace line. This will tell you where exactly it crashes and provide useful hints as to why it crashed.

Answer (score 1):

The line "Stack canary watchpoint triggered (network_event)" is your cue. It means the stack overrun detection triggered. One of the tasks (named "network_event") has used more stack that it's been allocated. Give it more.